# connect to windows server 2003 from redhat linux client through ssh

Tags: linux

I want to connect windows server 2003 remotely from red hat Linux client. I know that Linux has SSH but windows doesn't have. So is there any way.

Comment: What do you want to do after connecting? You need to run SSH server if you want to connect using ssh.

Answer (score -1):

sure

just install cygwin on your win machine and enable SSH (in the installer include ssh packages)

http://www.cygwin.com/

after that you can ssh to the win machine from your Linux machine.

enjoy

Answer (score -1):

I've written a little reminder for myself about installing sshd on Cygwin.
Please see [Cygwin install](http://linux.subogero.com/corporate-git/cygwin/) and [sshd install](http://linux.subogero.com/corporate-git/sshd/).

#### First install cygwin.

See cygwin.com. Follow the installation instructions. I recommend the following options:

```
Install from Internet
All Users
Use IE5 Settings
Select a mirror near you (if you can find out where they are!)
```

Make sure to Select Packages below (among others) besides the Base packages:

```
cygrunsrv
openssh
```

You can export the Windows user list to Cygwin.

```
$ cp /etc/passwd /etc/passwd.old    # backup for safety
$ mkpasswd > /etc/passwd
```

#### Start sshd

Next, start the Secure Shell Daemon (sshd) service on Windows

This will allow users on remote computers to log in to your box, get an interactive shell and do whatever they want. Or rather whatever you allow them to do. Remember?

There is a nice guide with a lot of troubleshooting info [here](http://chinese-watercolor.com/LRP/printsrv/cygwin-sshd.html).

In a nutshell. Start a Cygwin Shell window.

```
$ ssh-host-config -y
```

When prompted for “CYGWIN=”, type “tty ntsec”.

I do not allow login by password, only the public-key method. See below. So change the related line in `/etc/sshd_config` like this:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Finally start the service:

```
$ cygrunsrv --start sshd
```

#### Administering users with public-key authentication

`foo` wants to log in remotely to your box’s `bar` account.
He sends you his public RSA key `id_rsa.pub` in any way, email, pen-drive, whatever YOU trust.
If you find `foo` worthy, you authorize his key, and from then he will be able to log in to your `bar` account via ssh without typing `bar`’s password:

```
$ cat id_rsa.pub >> /home/bar/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. (I didn't downvote you, but that would be my guess. Also, this question is fairly off topic for the site, which probably doesn't help either.)